# Phonegap Android Database not connected in 2.3.4,2.3.5,2.3.6

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap android application. Im using database connection for this application. It working fine in android version 4.1.2. But not working in Android 2.3.6.
I get the following error **uncaught type error transaction callback must of valid type**.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too: Android 2.x requires a valid error callback for every transaction. Be sure to pass a function as the second parameter of db.transaction always. Android 4.x is looser with it's requirements.